# Jquery accordion scroll to selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For the usability of my accordion menu I need to make use of an autoscroll.

for now I created this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top 
}, 500);
```

This works OK, 'this' has the position of the clicked heading in the accordion. The problem I am facing is as follow. In the accordion are forms, these forms having various heights. When I expand the first accordion element, all is ok.
When I expand the second element with closing the accordion item above, still ok... The problem turns on when I don't close the accordion element by myself but hit just another accordion element to expand. I guess (which is logic) the calculation from the top of the document is mismatching.

What should I do to prevent this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: adding a http://jsfiddle.net demo would be appreciated

Comment: you need to check if particular accordion is clicked, close the others